# Modificar uma LinkedList utilizando outra LinkedList

Tags: java

tenho uma Lista1 e uma Lista2. A Lista1 é muito grande e a Lista2 possui alguns elementos da Lista1. Para evitar ficar buscando a Lista1 inteira para fazer uma modificação e assim perder performance, preciso ter uma Lista2 na qual posso alterar os dados de forma que também altere na Lista1.

Exemplo: minha lista um tem 250000 elementos. Preciso alterar o elemento 210100. Se eu tiver como fazer isso alterando uma segunda lista onde só tenho os dados que irei alterar futuramente, ganho mais performance.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você quer criar uma cópia da Lista e mantê-la atualizada? Por que quer fazer isso?

Comment: Nesse caso seria uma cópia, mas na verdade eu tenho uma Lista1 e uma Lista2. A Lista1 é muito grande e a Lista2 possui alguns elementos da Lista1. Para evitar ficar buscando a Lista1 inteira  para fazer uma modificação e assim perder performance, preciso ter uma Lista2 na qual posso alterar os dados de forma que também altere na Lista1.

Comment: Exemplo: minha lista um tem 250000 elementos. Preciso alterar o elemento 210100. Se eu tiver como fazer isso alterando uma segunda lista onde só tenho os dados que irei alterar futuramente, ganho mais performance.

Comment: É melhor você colocar essa informação na pergunta, como ela está você poderá receber respostas que não te atendem.

Comment: Você tem razão. Já alterei minha pergunta para ficar mais clara. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Já pensou em fazer a Lista2 ser um Map<Integer, Object> que possui como key o índice da Lista1 (o "endereço") e como value o Item que está na Lista1 nesse Índice?

Comment: Tu diz tabela Hash? Nunca ouvi falar desse Map. Posso pesquisar sobre.

Comment: Qual o tipo do dado que você está gravando no List?

Comment: Minha LinkedList é a seguinte: `public LinkedList<Evento> eventos = new LinkedList<>();`
Onde em Evento tenho getters e setters para os meus dados como price, por exemplo.
Tal lista é carregada com cerca de 250.000 posições. Tenho uma segunda lista, `public LinkedList<Evento> usuario = new LinkedList<>()`, a qual deve guardar algumas posições da primeira para eu modificar quando necessário, sem percorrer a primeira por inteira.

Comment: @Douglas Tabela Hash é uma estrutura de dados que pode ser usada para implementar, dentre outras coisas, o tipo abstrato Map. O conceito é uma coisa e a implementação é outra. Da mesma forma, LinkedList é uma implementação do conceito de List usando ponteiros, mas existem outras formas de fazer. É sempre interessante você pensar da forma mais abstrata possível, para não ficar preso a detalhes de implementação.

Answer (score 2):

O LinkedList do Java não expõe os Nodes internos, então não é possível você referenciar diretamente de um segundo LinkedList.

Se você quiser atualizar uma propriedade de um item da lista ao invés de trocar o item inteiro, basta adicionar o mesmo elemento em ambas as listas, que a referencia da memória será a mesma:

```
LinkedList<Evento> evento = new LinkedList<>();
LinkedList<Evento> usuario = new LinkedList<>();

Evento e = new Evento();

evento.add(e);
usuario.add(e);
//Altera uma propriedade numa lista:
usuario.getFirst().nome="Jose"; 

//Veja que se aplicou à outra lista também:
System.out.println(evento.getFirst().nome); //Jose
```

Caso você queira substituir o elemento completamente, você pode criar uma outra classe cuja única propriedade seja o Evento - digamos, EventoHolder, e adicionar o mesmo EventoHolder a ambas as listas.